# A good modern introduction to the information theoretic view of entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, resource-recommendations, information

Jaynes wrote a paper called information theory and statistical mechanics (1957). I tried to read this but found it somewhat hard to follow, and I suspect it's because it's one of the earlier works, and that a modern text might be more refined since we've had time to work it out. On the other hand, what I've read from physics textbooks don't explicitly talk about information theoretic concepts like shannon entropy.

Is there a good modern introduction to the information theoretic view of entropy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference for statistical mechanics from information theoretic view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233180/)

Comment: @sammygerbil, clearly not, everything referenced there is also written by Jaynes roughly at the same time, and I've already checked all of them. I'm asking for a **modern** introduction.

Comment: Sorry. I saw that but... I shall post some suggestions on above question.

Comment: Some of the later Jaynes papers are quite good - you can find a comprehensive list here bayes.wustl.edu/etj/node1.html . However, there have been more recent developments since Jaynes' death, particularly a focus on the Kullback-Leibler divergence rather than the Shannon entropy. I don't immediately know any great introductory treatments, though.

Comment: There is also tons of recent work relating to Szilard engines and the Landauer bound, which links thermodynamics to information in a very direct way. (Posting this mostly as a hint to someone who knows a good introductory treatment that they can post as an answer.)

Comment: @user83014 I have completed my answer to [Reference for statistical mechanics from information theoretic view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233180)